# Should Redirect to a common display/page on Custom Route/Page Not Found error in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, custom-routes

I am working on a Rails app. In my app, if I enter a custom route manually in the address bar/ as URL which is not present in **config/routes.rb**, it will show up the below given error message.

> Routing Error
>
> No route matches "/clientImage/blablahblah"

I want this to be redirected to a proper display for all the wrong routes given by the user either intentionally/unintentionally. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are probably working in development environment. In production, you just have to put a 404.html page in your public directory to customize the display

Comment: Yes, I'm in development env. Thanks for the information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When someone enters unsupported url Rails will raise ActionController::RoutingError. You can rescue this error and render 404 Not Found html.

Rails provides some special function called [rescue_from](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Rescuable/ClassMethods.html) for this purpose.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
   rescue_from ActionController::RoutingError, :with => :render_not_found
   rescue_from StandardError, :with => :render_server_error

   protected
     def render_not_found
        render "shared/404", :status => 404
     end

     def render_server_error
        render "shared/500", :status => 500
     end
end
```

Put your 404.html, 500.html in app/views/shared

Answer (score 2):

```
Yourapp::Application.routes.draw do
  #Last route in routes.rb
  match '*a', :to => 'errors#routing'
end
```

The "a" is actually a parameter in the Rails 3 Route Globbing technique. For example, if your url was /this-url-does-not-exist, then params[:a] equals "/this-url-does-not-exist". So be as creative as you'd like handling that rogue route.

In app/controllers/errors_controller.rb

```
 class ErrorsController < ApplicationController
      def routing
       render :file => "#{Rails.root}/public/404.html", :status => 404, :layout => false
      end
    end
```

Comment: This means I need to have 'match' statements for all the URL's(for each controller). right? That would be tedious task.